# Comparing files in list of string to files in target directory

Tags: vb.net

I have searched this issue for 2 days, without finding a solution. I might be using the wrong search terms, due to my limited knowledge of the subject.

I have 2 folders, a source and a target, each with files in them. I need to compare the files in these 2 dirs and delete the duplicate files from the target dir before moving the files from the source dir.

I have created a list of string for both dirs. But I can't seem to figure out how to make the dupes in the targetdir to get deleted instead of from the list itself. However, if I put targetdir or sourcedir in the File.Exists() and File.Delete(), it doesn't see the files.

My code is below. Can anyone help me with this?

```
Dim sourcedir As String
        sourcedir = TextBox1.Text + "\"
        Dim targetdir As String
        targetdir = readValue + "\"
        For Each filename In filelist
            If System.IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
                System.IO.File.Delete(filename)
            End If
        Next
```

Edit:
Thank you so very much. This is the code that I used, in case someone else has the same issue.

```
Dim sourcedir As String
        sourcedir = TextBox1.Text + "\"
        Dim targetdir As String
        targetdir = readValue + "\"
        Dim sourceFilePaths = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(sourcedir, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories)
        Dim targetFilePaths = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(targetdir, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories)

        'Compare only file names, ignoring paths, and get a list of duplicates.
        Dim duplicateFileNames = sourceFilePaths.Select(Function(filePath) System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath)).
                                                 Intersect(targetFilePaths.Select(Function(filePath) System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath)))

        'Combine target folder path with duplciate file names and delete each one.
        For Each filePath In duplicateFileNames.Select(Function(fileName) System.IO.Path.Combine(targetdir, fileName))
            System.IO.File.Delete(filePath)
            Application.DoEvents()
        Next
```

Comment: You should narrow that down to a [MCVE]; there seems to be a lot of unrelated code such as poking thru the registry.  You might answer your own question in the course of doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g.

```
Dim sourceFolderPath = "C:\SourceFolder"
Dim targetFolderPath = "C:\TargetFolder"

Dim sourceFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolderPath)
Dim targetFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles(targetFolderPath)

'Compare only file names, ignoring paths, and get a list of duplicates.
Dim duplicateFileNames = sourceFilePaths.Select(Function(filePath) Path.GetFileName(filePath)).
                                         Intersect(targetFilePaths.Select(Function(filePath) Path.GetFileName(filePath)))

'Combine target folder path with duplciate file names and delete each one.
For Each filePath In duplicateFileNames.Select(Function(fileName) Path.Combine(targetFolderPath, fileName))
    File.Delete(filePath)
Next
```

Here's an option that doesn't use LINQ:

```
Dim sourceFolderPath = "C:\SourceFolder"
Dim targetFolderPath = "C:\TargetFolder"

Dim sourceFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolderPath)
Dim targetFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles(targetFolderPath)

Dim sourceFileNames As New List(Of String)

For Each sourceFilePath In sourceFilePaths
    sourceFileNames.Add(Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath))
Next

For Each targetFilePath In targetFilePaths
    Dim targetFileName = Path.GetFileName(targetFilePath)

    If sourceFileNames.Contains(targetFileName) Then
        File.Delete(targetFilePath)
    End If
Next
```

It's important to note that both these examples are case-sensitive.  Both the `Intersect` and `Contains` methods will accept an `IEqualityComparer(Of String)` though, so you can provide one to make them case-insensitive.